# FindRoot outputs a lot of nlum and ReplaceAll errors before outputting (close) root

Tags: equation-solving

[image: The two functions I'm using]
I'm trying to find the root of the root function when some other variable is subtracted. I.e. 
`FindRoot[root[theta, r, h]-H, theta]`

Whenever I do this, FindRoot outputs a lot of error messages and then continues on to output a very close approximation to the root of the function. Can anyone shed any light onto why this is for me?

Error messages look like so:
[image: Errors]

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[θ_, r_, x_, h_] = 
  1/2 x (r^2 ArcCos[(r - x Cot[θ])/r] + (x Cot[θ] - r) Sqrt[
        x Cot[θ] (2 r - x Cot[θ])]) - π r^2 h;
```

Functions which use numeric techniques should have their arguments restricted to numeric values.

```
root[θ_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ] := 
 x /. FindRoot[f[θ, r, x, h], {x, 2}]

FindRoot[root[θ, 3.7, 2.6] - 10.7, {θ, 1}]

(*  {θ -> 1.24469}  *)

root[θ /. %, 3.7, 2.6] - 10.7

(*  3.55271*10^-15  *)

FindRoot[root[θ, 4, 2.2] - 10.7, {θ, 1}]

(*  {θ -> 1.25971}  *)

root[θ /. %, 4, 2.2] - 10.7

(*  -3.55271*10^-15  *)
```